# Change AngularJS location/route with $routeChangeSuccess previous property

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller Login that save the previous route like that :

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, currentRoute, previousRoute) {
  security.previousRoute = previousRoute;
});
```

So I save the previousRoute in my factory security...

Inside that factory I need change my location using that ! How can I do that? 
I tried that :

```
security.previousRoute.reload();
```

but that Route object does not have the reload method...

Thanks

My previousRoute object:

```
| y {params: Object, pathParams: Object, $$route: Object, loadedTemplateUrl: "/app/template/user/index.html", reloadOnSearch: true…}
 -  $$route: Object
 - loadedTemplateUrl: "/app/template/user.html"
 -  params: Object
 -  pathParams: Object
 -  __proto__: Object
```

Comment: this will not work because $location.path require string variable i recommend you using $locationChangeSuccess(newUrl, oldUrl).Meanwhile please wait for somebody else answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use $location property to set the url

```
$location.path(security.previousRoute);
```

Comment: Hello.. tried that and got thar error:

TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'charAt'

Comment: Well i have used this quite few times could you share your fiddle

Comment: I added the previousRoute object (debug mode) ... It seems right to you?

Comment: I am also getting the "TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'charAt'" error. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: `charAt()` is something you'd do to a string, so it sounds like the object you're sending to `$location.path` isn't a string. Just a guess. :)

Comment: `$location.path()` expect its argument to be string. I have no idea why this answer is accepted and upvoted!

Comment: Well basically code should be changed to `$location.path(security.previousRoute.originalPath)`. I think that should do the trick. Answer is probably accepted because it pointed OP in the right direction.