# Change AngularJS location with stored route

Tags: angularjs, location

I am trying to store the "next route" argument of $routeChangeStart inside a service and call $location.path() with the "next route" from a different place. To clarify here some code:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    service.nextRoute = next;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('event:someEvent');
});
```

...now I catch the event and try to do something like (assume that the services used are all properly injected and available):

```
$rootScope.$on('event:someEvent', function() {
    //do some stuff
    $location.path(service.nextRoute);
});
```

what I get is a `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'charAt'` error from the call to `$locaton.path(service.nextRoute);`. There is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066717/change-angularjs-location-route-with-routechangesuccess-previous-property/) here on StackOverflow with a similar problem but the proposed solution doesn't seem to work? So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path()` take a string where `next` is a `route {}` object.  It sounds like you actually want to capture `$locationChangeStart` instead which will give you access to the path.

```
scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newVal, oldVal) {
});
```

It is an undocumented feature according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14700326/181776).